# Numerical solution to an integral equation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, code-request, integral-equations

I know this question mayn't be new, but here is my problem: I have to solve this integral equation (numerically, of course, except from very few special cases):

$$\phi_{\nu}(t) = 1 - q\int_0^t \frac{d\psi_{\nu}}{d t'} \phi_{\nu}(t - t')\ dt'$$

Where of course I know what $\psi$ is. I can choose $q = 1$.

I tried to take a look at some past answers, but I did not find what I was looking for. The problem may be that this is a convolution integral.

Comment: I recently looked into [a similar matrix equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/147086/34008). The proposed solution is that if your model allows it to change the lower boundary of the integral to be $t-c$ with $c$ a constant, then you can discretize the integral using some formula (e.g. Trapezoidal rule) and solve the obtained delay equation.

Comment: Perhaps, this question belongs in [math.SE] instead of Mathematica.SE,

Comment: @bbgodfrey Since I wanted to have a mathematica code to solve that, I don't see how it should belong to Math SE, people over there won't provide me for a code in that sense...

Comment: Mathematica certainly can reproduce the calculation by @CraigTracy, but no further progress can be made without an expression for `g[s]`.  Given that expression, it may be possible to use `InverseLaplaceTransform` to obtain the desired answer.  Am alternative approach is to discretize your integral equation to form a matrix equation, which can be inverted to obtain a numerical answer.

Answer (score 3):

This problem can be solved using the Laplace transform of a function $f$:
$$ \hat{f}(s):=\int_0^\infty e^{-s t} f(t)\, dt. $$
Your equation can be written as
$$ f(t)=1-q\int_0^t f(t-t') g(t')\, dt'. $$
Taking the Laplace transform of both sides and using the convolution property of the Laplace transform one gets
$$ \hat{f}(s) = 1/s - q\, \hat{f}(s)\,\hat{g}(s). $$
Solving this for $\hat{f}$ gives
$$ \hat{f}(s)=(1/s) \left(1+q\,\hat{g}(s)\right)^{-1}.$$
Now use the inverse transform to find $f(t)$.